# App not hitting https server on local environment

Tags: ios, nginx

I have an ios app which invokes `sfsafariviewcontroller` where i am hitting on ip with the following url `https://192.168.216.141:443/..`

It is running on nginx server with config

```
server {
        listen       443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate localhost.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key localhost.key;
        server_name  localhost;
        underscores_in_headers on;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload;";
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
        add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';

        location ~ __handshake__ {
            # proxy_pass http://wsbackend;
            proxy_pass        http://websocket;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_read_timeout 300s;
        }

        location / {
            root        /Users/../../;
            autoindex on;
        }

        location /payments {
            alias        /Users/../..;
            autoindex on;
        }

    }
```

But when I invoke the app, it does not hit my server. And when same thing is done on non-ssl environment it is working and hitting server.

Is there any way we can hit local `https` server fro app?

Update

I am getting this error

```
WebSocket network error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -9807.)
```

Comment: It's probably that iOS is particular about the certificate being valid, so it needs to be signed by a CA and the certificate name needs to match `192.168.216.141`.

Comment: yes i had to add certificates in ios device and install it.